# Get notified when celery workers die

Tags: python, celery

Where's the best place to get notified when celery workers die?

I'm aware of the `worker_shutdown` signal but does it get called also in sudden death of workers?

I have these pdf rendering workers and they suddenly died or at least became unresponsive to remote control commands so I'm looking for ways so I can get notified when things like this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worker can't trigger signals after it has been killed.

The best way would be to write a plugin for Nagios, Munin or similar to notify when
the number of workers decrease.  See the Monitoring and Management guide in the Celery documentation.

Comment: Can we know if the worker controller kills one of it's PoolWorkers?